# How can I do docker registry gc in openshift docker registry?

Tags: openshift, docker-registry, openshift-origin

I have deployed a docker reigstry in openshift, https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/docker_registry.html

How can I run garbage collection in openshift docker registry?
https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/pruning_resources.html#pruning-images covers the "prune" command which purges unused images and their metadata.  That is a superset of registry garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks, prune is very useful.